# Magento 2 Import: Escaping HTML and quotes

Tags: csv, magento, magento2, magento2.2

In my CSV, some of the fields have double quotes and single quotes. Whenever I try to import products with said file, it breaks. Now, I've tried changing single quote  with `&#39;` and double quote `&#34;`, but it didn't help. I have also tried changing it those to `\'` and `\"`, respectively, but that didn't help either. What's the proper way to escape single and double quotes for CSV product import for Magento 2?

FWIW, my fields are not wrapped with double quotes, so I left Enclosure option in Magento 2 Import unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, if your enclosure is double quote, and you check option `Field enclosure` during import. you don't need to escape double quotes. That being said, you need to escape single quotes, and the best way to do it is to use ASCII HTML code for single quote: `&#39;`.